# Div centered with 5px margin-left, right, top and bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div that is centered (horizontally and vertically).  It should change size with the screen, but have 5 pixel margins all around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#thediv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```